# Can server identify clients IP if accessed by a proxy site

Tags: ip-address

Can server able to retrive Ip address of client if client access the server by using a proxy site.Will the ip address of client is visible to server?

Comment: i don't think so, The server will see the ip of proxy

Comment: I tried for this but i dint get any valid answers till..

Comment: I need more answers pls upvote so that others can try to answer.

Comment: You want to understand if the client use proxy or the real client ip when he's using proxy?

Answer (score 0):

It depends how the proxy is set up. A proxy can be set up to make this very easy or to make it very difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Web page can contain scripts / resources that will perform a request from client directly to server, such the server can expose the real IP behind the proxy.